# Multiplying the ticket value when ticket quantity is changed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote a simple code for entering ticket quantity. Here is the code:
**`HTML code:`**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Book Now</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-7 padding_null ticket_qty">Tickets Quantity</label>
        <input class="col-md-5 padding_null text-center" id="demo3" type="text" value="1" name="demo3">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row margin_null">
          <label class="col-md-7 padding_null ticket_qty">Total Cost</label>
          <label class="col-md-5 padding_null ticket_qty">$199</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block proceed_btn">Proceed</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**`JS code:`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });

  $("input[name='demo3']").TouchSpin();

});
```

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/0b7qf12p/
When I change the ticket quantity, ticket price should be updated accordingly. i.e., if I choose ticket quantity as 2, then ticket price should become 398. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can hook to the `touchspin.on.startspin` event of the touchSpin plugin, and update the text of the required element (note that I put an `id` on it to make selection easier). Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    $("#demo3").TouchSpin().on('touchspin.on.startspin', function() {
        $('#total').text('$' + (this.value * 199));     
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0b7qf12p/1/)

Comment: Check the console for errors in your system. Make sure you've included jQuery properly and are running your code under document.ready

Comment: Checked everything here.. Everything is good, but your code isn't working

Comment: Have you added the `total` id to the relevant label?

Comment: Yeah, I've added it... I'm getting output like this: https://postimg.org/image/9c70f1kox/

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help any further then. If there's no errors in the console then it should be working as per the fiddle I posted

Comment: Got it now. I changed the code to: `$("input[name='demo3']").TouchSpin().on('touchspin.on.startspin', function() {
            $('#total').text('$' + (this.value * 199));     
        });`

Comment: Glad you got it fixed, although your HTML does have the `#demo3` element. If that selector doesn't work then you should ensure you don't have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Answer (score 0):

here is some pseudo code to give you the idea...

```
$("#demo3").on("change", function() {
   $("#priceOutput").html($(this).val() * ticketPrice);
});
```